# SQL Server IN (Select) results in not terminating query

Tags: sql-server

I have narrowed down the problem to a minimum example. There should be more columns which I would select for the top level in the actual query that I want to run.

Query:

```
SELECT [AspNetUsers].Id
FROM [Trade_US_PC]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] ON ([Trade_US_PC].[TraderUserID] = [AspNetUsers].[Id])
WHERE [Trade_US_PC].[ID] IN (SELECT TOP 10 [Trade_US_PC].[ID] 
                             FROM [Trade_US_PC]
                             INNER JOIN [Item] ON ([Trade_US_PC].[ItemID] = [Item].[ID])
                             WHERE ([Trade_US_PC].[ItemTraitsID] = 14)
                             ORDER BY [Item].[Name_EN])
```

The `IN (SELECT ID)` trick was something I learned from MySQL which could speed up `ORDER BY` in some cases. But it is certainly not doing its job here.

This query has been running for more than two hours and is still executing.

All columns in the query are indexed. All ID are primary key cluster index

Query Plan:

[image]

Here is the interesting part: The subquery (`SELECT TOP 10`...) only takes 1s to run.

Query Plan:

[image]

IO Stat:

> (10 row(s) affected)
>   Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>    Table 'Item'. Scan count 1, logical reads 38, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>    Table 'Trade_US_PC'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2443, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

If I replace the subquery with the 10 IDs returned from the subquery then the whole query takes also 1s to run.

Query Plan:

[image]

IO Stat:

> (10 row(s) affected)
>   Table 'AspNetUsers'. Scan count 0, logical reads 20, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Trade_US_PC'. Scan count 10, logical reads 30, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

And finally if I get rid of the `IN(SELECT ID)` trick it will also take 1s to run

```
SELECT top 10 [AspNetUsers].Id
FROM [Trade_US_PC]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] ON ([Trade_US_PC].[TraderUserID] = [AspNetUsers].[Id])
INNER JOIN Item on Item.ID = ItemID
WHERE [Trade_US_PC].[ItemTraitsID] = 14 
ORDER BY [Item].[Name_EN]
```

Query Plan: 
[image]

IO Stat:

> (10 row(s) affected)
>   Table 'Item'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3716, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'Trade_US_PC'. Scan count 44, logical reads 990999, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
>   Table 'AspNetUsers'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

There are roughly 400k rows in `Trade_US_PC` table, 8k rows in `Item` Table and 50 rows in `AspNetUsers` table

I have tried this in SQL server 2012 and LocalDB (16G ram + SSD). Both yields the same result. While the query is executing, the CPU usage is around 10-15%, 0MB Disk IO and ram usage is same as not running this query.
Any idea why this happened?

Comment: Look at the Key-Lookup in the first ex. plan. can you eliminate that using an covering index?

Comment: @FLICKER yea tried that before I post the question. It would eliminate the key-lookup and use Sort + Hash Match. But the result is unchanged

Comment: That is not valid systax.  ( ) don't add up.

Comment: @Frisbee looks like the person helped me to format it accidently removed it. Fixed

Comment: top 10 is non deterministic without and order by

Comment: finally, are you asking for solution or you just want to know why this is happening?

Comment: @FLICKER first I want to know why this is happening. An alternative would be to not use the select ID trick but that would slow down some of my other queries

Comment: @Frisbee now it is in the right form

Comment: First try to use EXISIT instead of IN. As another alternative you can try having the TOP 10 as a CTE. if it did not work too you can store the TOP 10 into a table variable and then use EXISIT. You also can try update statistics on your table. you tables are pretty small. But I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: @FLICKER the table variable method works perfectly. I will use that as a work around in the mean while. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're welcome! I still am interested to see why this happens. If you found the answer, please post it here. it would be helpful to compare the execution plan when using table variable vs sub-query

Comment: I'd also follow up @FLICKER suggestion of trying out `NOT EXIST`  then compare all three query plans. (Original, Generally I have found `IN (SELECT..)` to the worst performer because sometimes the query planner has difficulty understanding the statistics of the inner select result. A giveaway for a bad plan is when actual rowcounts vary wildly from estimated rowcounts.

Comment: when you use select  + order inside IN (...) then you are using Loop twice + Scan, while if you used exists, it would be much faster since it will scan to find first occurrence

Comment: @HadiHassan 2hours of execution yields no result seems fishy to me

Comment: @Steve, do you have update-statistics and index-rebuild jobs scheduled?

Comment: @Steve you should prepare a maintenance plan with such actions and schedule it, let's say, to be executed once per week at night (to avoid blocking of other activity). First article with pictures I found right now: https://www.targetprocess.com/guide/installation/database-maintenance-recommendations/ (part with t-sql is relevant to that product only, not relevant to you)